# How to add files to a maven project executing generate goal (mvn archetype:generate)?

Tags: maven

I'm building a maven archetype project. As parameter (serviceDescriptor), I'm passing path to an xml file. When the generate goal is successfully executed, I would like to have the serviceDescriptor file in src/main/resources. Based on maven archetype documentation, it seems that is not possible but, there should be a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent couple of days on this and I think that I have found a reasonable solution.

As I mention in the question, I'm passing the file path as required property to the archetype:generate.
I had to implement a simple plug-in that is executed after archetype generate is finishing. This plug-in is coping the file into src/main/resources, read some data from the file and update the pom.xml setting some properties. In order to be able to modify the pom.xml file I'm using maven-model-2.0 archetype as dependency in maven plug-in. It offers Maven MvenXpp3Reader and MavenXpp3Writer classes that allows to safe modify pom.xml.

In order to tell to archetype project to execute plug-in at the end of generate phase of archetype:

```
mvn archetype:generate -goals=plugin_groupId:plugin_artifactId:goal
```

The downside is that the plug-in should be available in a accessible repository or local repo.